# Create 3D Object out of 3 views

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, geometry

I'd like to calculate an 3D object out of the 3 views. The principle is shown in following figure. [image: object with 3 views]

Each view is stored in a 2 dimensional matrix with binary values representing the object. The 3D object should be stored in a 3 dimensional matrix also with binary values (True: this pixel is representing object mass, False: this pixel is white space).
How can I realize this with simply numpy matrix operations?

The three views `a,b and c` can for example look like `[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]`.

Comment: See [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23409318/553404) for some more input data examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your views are `a, b, c` then:

```
result = a[None, :, :] & b[:, None, :] & c[:, :, None]
```

Shuffle round the axes to suit the input

`a`, `b` and `c` are assumed to be of the form:

```
np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.bool)
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But could you please add how the arrays `a, b and c` are built? I'd build them like `[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]`. This would be a square in an image with 4x4 pixel. Each sub-array stands for a row consisting of single pixels.

Comment: Updated - if you want to add a specific example of input data I'll update the question to suit