# Three 2d profiles to 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Is there a staking method available within numpy to convert three 2d profiles into a 3d array? Where x is the straight on view, y is the horizontal view and z is the birds eye view. Whereby if in a 3d space each value in the x,y and z are all equal to 1 maintain the value of 1 otherwise give a value of 0. So in this small example there should be 108 unique values I believe (9*12)...

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1]])

y = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
             [ 1, 1, 1],
             [ 0, 1, 1],
             [ 0, 0, 1]])

z = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
             [ 0, 1, 1],
             [ 0, 0, 1],
             [ 0, 0, 0]])
```

i.e. if we start from the `x` array at `[0, 0]` the value is `1`, at position `y[0,0]` the value is also `1` however at `z[0, 0]` the value is `0` so the 3d array of `xyz` should be `0` at `[0,0,0]`. Using the same positions of `x` and `y` but changing `z` to position `z[0, 1]` is a value of `1` as well so the `xyz` 3d array at location `[0, 0, 1]` should be `1`. So it should be a number of permutations essentially creating a rectangular 3D grid.

Comment: Very similar to: [Create 3D Object out of 3 views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291532/create-3d-object-out-of-3-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine broadcasting and bitwise/logical operations to do this:

```
>>> x[np.newaxis, :, :] & y[:, np.newaxis, :] & z[:, :, np.newaxis]
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
>>>
```